# RSpec stub with unexpected results

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am doing a command line of game of [Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock](http://www.samkass.com/theories/RPSSL.html) in Ruby. I have the `matchup` method that takes the variables `@shape` (the hand shape randomly selected by the game) and `@player_shape` (the hand shape chosen by the player).

My `matchup` method compares the two shapes and sets the game result to `@result`:

```
class Game
  SHAPES = [:rock, :paper, :scissors, :lizard, :spock]
  attr_reader :shape, :player_shape, :status

  # ...

  def matchup
    if @shape == @player_shape
      @result = :draw
    else
      case @player_shape
      when :rock
        @result = (@shape == :scissors || @shape == :lizard) ? :player_wins : :game_wins
      when :paper
        @result = (@shape == :rock || @shape == :spock) ? :player_wins : :game_wins
      when :scissors
        @result = (@shape == :paper || @shape == :lizard) ? :player_wins : :game_wins
      when :lizard
        @result = (@shape == :paper || @shape == :spock) ? :player_wins : :game_wins
      when :spock
        @result = (@shape == :rock || @shape == :scissors) ? :player_wins : :game_wins
      end
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

I ran the code many times and it works as expected, but in my spec file, the result I'm getting is not matching the code behavior. Here is the spec:

```
describe Game do
  subject(:game) { Game.new }
  # ...
  describe "#matchup" do
    context "game chooses rock" do
      before do
        allow(game).to receive(:shape).and_return(:rock)
      end

      it "sets result as :player_wins if the game chooses paper" do
        allow(game).to receive(:player_shape).and_return(:paper)

        game.matchup

        expect(game.result).to eq(:player_wins)
     end
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the result:

```
Failure/Error: expect(game.result).to eq(:player_wins)

   expected: :player_wins
        got: :draw

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -:player_wins
   +:draw
```

What I am doing wrong here? I've tried and tried and still can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
allow(game).to receive(:shape).and_return(:rock)
```

and there

```
allow(game).to receive(:player_shape).and_return(:paper)
```

You're stubbing methods `Game#shape` and `Game#player_shape` for `game` object.
But you're using `@shape == @player_shape` as condition in `if` statement.

Ruby treats undefined instance variables (those which starts from `@`) as `nil` by default.

```
→ irb
irb(main):001:0> @shape
=> nil
```

Thus `@shape == @player_shape` is the same as `nil == nil` in your case. Which is actually a `true`. What's why program flow reach `@result = :draw` line.

To make it work you need to define `shape` and `player_shape` methods by using [attr_reader](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader), for example, and use them instead of instance variables.

**upd**

Now replace `@shape` with `shape` and `@player_shape` with `player_shape` in your code. Be sure you initialise values for them.

Take a look at [that Ruby Monk tutorial](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/110-instance-variables) (or any other articles) about instance vairables to understand how they work

Comment: I've added the methods `shape` and `player_shape` and it is still giving me the same result. (I've updated the question to show that)